# Signaling mechanism for webRTC using simpleWebRTC js library and backend in django

Tags: node.js, django, webrtc, django-channels, simplewebrtc

I am trying to build video conferencing web application where multiple people can join the call and there will be video/audio/data transmission. I researched a lot for this. What i understand is we can achieve this using webRTC protocol. I started doing research for js libraries and i came to know for ***simpleWebRTC***. I want to develop with backend as a django. I tried to run sample demo code from https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-simplewebrtc/. but i am not able to establish connection with socket.io which is simplewebRTC signaling sandbox server.
I tried with node express server as well, but still i got the same error:- **net::ERR_FAILED**. This error occured in simplewebrtc-with-adapter-js while making connection.
What would be the correct technologies to achieve this type of functionality?

Front-end webRTC libraries:- simplewebRTC/ EasyRTC/ Any else apis?

Signaling mechanism:- What and how can we use to connect with webRTC?

Backend:- Node js/Django?

I still confused with the signaling protocols/STUN/TURN servers as we have to define the servers by our self. simpleWebRTC is not providing that which we can use in production.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just started a video calling and chat application as well. [open-easyrtc](https://github.com/open-easyrtc/open-easyrtc), no problems so far, their demo just works after `npm install`.

As for signaling servers, since I just started I haven't concerned myself much about them but the most I can make out of it is it's used for exchanging information like video metadata, network information, etc. open-easyrtc comes with public STUN and TURN servers, not sure about the limitation especially if you're going to have a lot of users.

It's also possible to deploy your own, I'm looking at learning more about [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)
once I finished developing my application.

Comment: I have a requirement for more number of users. I came up with use of media servers. But still not achieved what i want to.

Comment: @khushalishah how many users are you looking at? by the way, by number of users I mean the total number using your application, not the number of users talking with each other in a room. Also if you're not deploying to the internet, this shouldn't be an issue as you don't need STUN/TURN servers for local network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer), a simple library for webrtc. Here is an example project with multiple users [project](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer), [DEMO](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is socket.io is suffcient for signaling mechanism in production where number of people is very high?

Comment: @khushalishah yes it is

Comment: @khushalishah if it answered your question you can mark it as resolved

Comment: Still i am not cleared with the whole process. Can you refer something which is something i can get full understanding of how can get started to make this kind of application. I researched a lot but i want proper understanding with sample demo project or code. The above sample example is just about switching camera. I want something like video conferencing like zoom, skype but on web, which is peer-peer communication.

Comment: @khushalishah have you checked the link in my answer?

Comment: I checked it but it is just simple your local video, My concern is about multi user group call and it should handle more number of people in single session.

Comment: @khushalishah Just open in multiple tabs and its multi user